# unexpected indentation behaviour with latexindent

Tags: latexindent

I have the following file that is part of one of my custom classes:

```latex
% actual latexindent output:
\DeclareDocumentCommand {\chapterformat}  { } { \thechapter }
 \DeclareDocumentCommand {\sectionformat} { } {\thesection}
  \DeclareDocumentCommand \subsectionformat { } {\thesubsection}
    \DeclareDocumentCommand \subsubsectionformat {} {\thesubsubsection}
    \DeclareDocumentCommand \paragraphformat {} {\theparagraph}
    \DeclareDocumentCommand \subparagraphformat {} {\thesubparagraph}
```

The source code you see here is the exact output after running `latexindent`.
However, instead I would expect to have an output like

```latex
% expected latexindent output:
\DeclareDocumentCommand {\chapterformat}  { } { \thechapter }
\DeclareDocumentCommand {\sectionformat} { } {\thesection}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \subsectionformat { } {\thesubsection}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \subsubsectionformat {} {\thesubsubsection}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \paragraphformat {} {\theparagraph}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \subparagraphformat {} {\thesubparagraph}
```

Obviously, `latexindent` is applying the rules for indenting sectioning commands here, as per my configuration:

```yaml
# from latexindentconfig.yaml
indentAfterHeadings:
    part:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 0
       level: 1
    chapter:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 1
       level: 2
    section:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 1
       level: 4
    subsection:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 1
       level: 8
    subsection*:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 0
       level: 9
    subsubsection:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 0
       level: 10
    paragraph:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 0
       level: 11
    subparagraph:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 0
       level: 12
```

I like indenting the sectioning, but not the definitions, and I feel like I never told `latexindent` to indent my definitions. Clearly, there is a gap between my expectations and the actual functionality.

The question now is: How do I tell `latexindent` not to apply to the definitions of sectioning commands?

Comment: Perhaps a local file `latexindent.yaml`  that turns off the switches for this file `indentAfterThisHeading: 0`

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following file that is part of one of my custom classes

Given that this is part of a class file, I'd recommend switching off the `indentAfterHeadings` as in

### latexindent.yaml

```yaml
indentAfterHeadings:
    chapter:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 0
    section:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 0
    subsection:
       indentAfterThisHeading: 0
```

and then run

```
latexindent.pl -l myfile.tex
```

If you'd like to call the `yaml` file something else, say `marc.yaml` then you'd call

```
latexindent.pl -l marc.yaml myfile.tex
```